# how to implement lazy loading inside nested scroll view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to add lazy loading for my app but when i put the new controller. the controller didn't work with the NestedScrollView that i've made.
my new controller:

```
final controller = ScrollController();
```

in my initstate:

```
controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
        getStoryUser();
      }
```

and i put the controller into list view but its didn't work with the NestedScrollView that i've mentioned earlier. any solution for this matter? any help will be valuable thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692774/how-to-implement-listview-lazyload-inside-a-nestedscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Attach this _scrollController with your scrollview

```
if ((_scrollController.position.pixels >
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 20)) {
      if (_isLoading || _loadMore || ((_media.media?.length ?? 0) < 30)) {
        return;
      }
      _pageNumber++;
      _loadMore = true;
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
        await _loadData();

      _loadMore = false;
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    }
```